# Assertequls method is not working

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
 boolean   b = Testfactory.read_element_file(models).equals(ExcelUtils.readdata("Model Export.xlsx"));

 SoftAssert ass = new SoftAssert();
 ass.assertEquals(b, true);
```

in boolean b i comparing two list after debugging i am getting b value is false but the assert is not getting failed. Junit test cases showing passed.Please have a look the attched screen shot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyPtu.png)

Comment: Simply use `Assert.assertEquals()` instead of `SoftAssert`.

Comment: I would suggest to use `Assert.assertTrue(b);`

Comment: Glad I could help, please wote if You liked.

Answer (score 4):

`SoftAssert` doesn't throws an exception, From the [docs](http://static.javadoc.io/org.testng/testng/6.8.8/org/testng/asserts/SoftAssert.html#SoftAssert())

> When an assertion fails, don't throw an exception but record the
>   failure. Calling assertAll() will cause an exception to be thrown if
>   at least one assertion failed.

Use regular assert or call `assertAll()`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use simple

```
Assert.assertTrue(b);
```

hope this helps,